# ros rviz cpp implementation available?

Tags: navigation, mapping, c++, rviz, drone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to create a GUI which will link with rivz. Rather than open up the whole of rivz, I'm trying to just have the grid (only, not all those other rviz components) opened up, and ready to plot the trajectory of my robot. I was therefore wondering if it is possible at all for me to do this? I assume that if it were possible it would require me to use some rviz cpp libraries (however I can't find any!).

Any advice would also be helpful. At the end of the day I would just like to plot the x,y,z trajectory of my drone over a grid of some sort. Rviz just seemed the natural way to go about it since I'm working in ROS. If there is any easier method don't hesitate to let me know.

Cheers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191377/ros-rviz-cpp-implementation-available?/) by [pche8701](https://answers.ros.org/users/20096/pche8701/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/librviz_tutorial/html/index.html) looks like it describes something very similar to what you want to achieve.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pche8701](https://answers.ros.org/users/20096/pche8701/) on 2014-08-27**:
Yup, I've tried to implement/download this tutorial except it doesn't seem to be working:

1. I've followed the instructions to sudo apt-get install etc..., except when I get up to rosrun librviz_tutorial myviz, there is no 'myviz' (no tab autocomplete, it's not there)
2. I've tried to manually build the files of the tutorial, but there is an error with linking in the ogre files (I've tried to alter their CMakeLists.txt file, which was made for an older version of ROS (I'm using Hyrdo)). Error: undefined reference to `rviz::RenderPanel::RenderPanel(QWidget*) etc... (should I post up my CMakeLists file?)

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-08-28**:
Ok, I just checked on my machine and the .deb package indeed seems to be empty (apart from a package.xml that gets installed). The error you are getting is a linker error, so take a look if your linker setup (target_link_libraries etc.) is correct.